# How to play both Video and audio in all the Browsers

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to do my website adding only a Video Loop ( with Audio) and I am starting to make it according this WebGL example here
https://www.creativebloq.com/how-to/create-a-webgl-3d-landing-page
After that I remplaced the video source of this project with the mine one (it has both Video and audio) in the Index.html amd I can see the Video succesfully but I cannot heard its audio.
Since I read I might be faced with the autoplay policy of modern browsers.( That means at least with Chrome, you can’t automatically play a video with sound), for it, I can fix this problem easily solve this issue by forcing a user interaction before you start to playback the video.
To be more specific, I add a link with an example of that I need to make for your knownledge

https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_video

Like I am new in this topic, Could anybody help me to add the code to the example mentioned before to build the background and the Button to play both Video and Audio together? Could anybody help me with it?
One part of code I have is the following

```
    <script>

      // vars
      var num=30;
        var objects=[];
        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster();
        var mouse = new THREE.Vector2();
      var light,t;

        // create camera
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 65, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        camera.position.set(0.0,0.0,5);

        // create a scene
        var scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // create renderer
      var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

</script>

<h1> My own website </h1>

<video id="videoBacker" loop src="assets/miownvideo.mp4" autoplay muted ></video>
<div class='bar-top'></div>
<div class='bar-bottom'></div>
```

Comment: Any specific reason for using WebGLRenderer ? why don't you use the the media element of html 5 to play mp4 file. for more information :(https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110113/video.html#media-elements)

Comment: Just remove the `muted` attribute ?

Comment: Hi Kaiido. I removed the muted attribute and the Chrome only show me a still frame ( not sound) Thanks for your advice

Comment: Hi  mail2subhajit, I am making my website woth WebGl because after I want to modifw it to WebVR... Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Well it seems you already know how you should handle this don't you? In your "user interaction" handler, you call `video.play()` and you're ok to run.

Comment: Hi Kaiido, Sorry for m daring for this but since I am new about this topic, Could you give an Index.html complete code example to add this user interaction handler in the my own code? Thanks to your help again

Comment: Hi mail2subhajit. For your advice, I am building one HTML 5 project and I can see and heard both audio and video but I cannot autoplay it( I added in my code autoplay attribute but the Video/Audio only play one frame in Chrome and Firefox ( only works fine in Microsoft Edge Browser) Could you help me to fix it? Thanks for your time